# Чому мова солов'їна?

Tags: значення-слів

***Чому мова солов'їна?***

> Любіть Україну, як сонце, любіть,
>
> як вітер, і трави, і води,
>
> в годину щасливу і в радості мить,
>
> любіть у годину негоди!
>
> Любіть Україну у сні й наяву,
>
> вишневу свою Україну,
>
> красу її, вічно живу і нову,
>
> і мову її ***солов'їну.***
>
> Для нас вона в світі єдина, одна
>
> в просторів солодкому чарі...
>
> Вона у зірках, і у вербах вона,
>
> і в кожному серця ударі...
>
> Як та купина, що горить —— не згора,
>
> живе у стежках, у дібровах,
>
> у зойках гудків, і у хвилях Дніпра,
>
> і в хмарах отих пурпурових.
>
> Любіть у коханні, в труді, у бою,
>
> як пісню, що лине зорею...
>
> Всім серцем любіть Україну свою —
>
> і вічні ми будемо з нею!

Сосюра Володимир

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Соловей - це птах, що його вважають за одного з найбільш співочих, такого, що має найкрасивіший спів.

І так вважають не лише українці, читаємо у "Спорідненостях за вибором"/"Вибіркових спорідненостях" (die Wahlverwandtschaften) Ґьоте (переклад мій, довільний):

> In manchen Tönen ist die Nachtigall noch Vogel; dann steigt sie über ihre Klasse hinüber und scheint jedem Gefiederten andeuten zu wollen, was eigentlich singen heiße.
>
> В деяких тонах соловей залишається птахом; але потім він вивищується над своїм класом і, здається, хоче дати зрозуміти всім опереним, що насправді значить слово співати.

Отже В. Сосюра наголошує на співучости української мови, порівнює її звучання зі співом солов'я.